# SceneKit: Rendering without a SCNView?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm currently working with SceneKit as a way to simulate some basic physics. For my use case, I'm trying to run simulations in many SCNScenes, but I don't really need to render out each scene to the screen. Is it possible to have my scenes render (`applyForce`, `applyTorque` etc still work) without rendering to an SCNView?

Comment: You can use a tiny and almost transparent scnview to achieve your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an `SCNView` to work with SceneKit but you can save a lot of rendering time by making your rootNode invisible.

In your `SCNScene` initialization:

```
self.rootNode.hidden=true;
```